VBA for / .find loop will not skip to the next line
i have a VBA script i built to search column H for one value, and if a second value exists in column D-G of the same row, it should modify the quantity in column I. if the value is not found in that row, it should keep searching.
this works fine for most of the entries, but on some of the entries there were too many potential codes to fit in just 4 columns, so i added another row on some parts with the same value in column H, but the rest of the values it should look for in columns D-G. since the script is suppose to check column H, find value 1, check column D-G for value 2, and if not found, continue searching, i thought it would continue to the next row and find what it was looking for. however, that is not the case.
it works great at finding the correct line if the second value its looking for is on top, but if its on the second row, it cannot find it. i've included a snippet of the excel sheet as an example.
Private Sub RemoveStock_Click()
 Dim EmptyRange As Range
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J1").Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J2").Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J3").Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J4").Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Text
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "no Quantity has been entered"
    End If
    Range("H4").Select
    
Dim BHM
Dim DT
Dim BHMrng As Range
Dim DTrng As Range
Dim rnmb
Dim cel As Range
Dim found
found = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("Z4").Value
BHM = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J1").Value
DT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J2").Value
Range("H4").Activate
Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
    Set DTrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory").Columns("H:H").Find(DT, Range("H" & ActiveCell), xlValues, xlWhole, 1, 1, 0)
    If Not DTrng Is Nothing Then
    DTrng.Activate
        For Each cel In Range(DTrng.Offset(0, -4), DTrng.Offset(0, -1))
            If cel.Value = BHM Then
            DTrng.Offset(0, 1).Value = DTrng.Offset(0, 1).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J3").Value
            found = "1"
            ElseIf cel.Value = "Misc." Then
            DTrng.Offset(0, 1).Value = DTrng.Offset(0, 1).Value + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J3").Value
            found = "1"
            End If
            
            If found = "1" Then
            Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
        
    If found = "1" Then
    Exit For
    End If
    End If
    
Next x
If found = "" Then
MsgBox "no matching BHM for Detail #"
End If
    


If found = "1" Then
found = ""
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Range("J1:J4").ClearContents
End Sub

Worksheet:


Offhand its seems this: For Each cel In Range(DTrng.Offset(0, -4), DTrng.Offset(0, -1)) should be changed to this: For Each cel In Range(DTrng.Offset(0, -4), DTrng.Offset(1, -1)) - so that you search a range of 2x4 (two rows, four cols) instead of 1x4 (one row, 4 cols).

Ah, forget my advice above ... it will work when you "find" the first row and look in the row below it, but it won't work when you "find" the second row (which really belongs with the first row). You will have to incorporate a little more logic about "do I need to search in a second row" ... maybe just based on blanks in other columns in the row below or something like that ... a little bit if IF logic basically, so you can check two rows when you need to, and also not search in a second row because it is checked already.

Did you merge the cells in Col I where you added "extra" rows?

On matching the DT value, you can check Col I to see if there are merged cells there, and then search the relevant rows in Col D:G
Untested:
Private Sub RemoveStock_Click()
    
    Dim wsLog As Worksheet, wsInv As Worksheet
    Dim BHM, DT, cel As Range, found, v
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long, iColRows As Long
    
    Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
    Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
    
    wsLog.Range("J1").Value = Me.TextBox1.Text 'use `Me` if this code is in a userform
    wsLog.Range("J2").Value = Me.TextBox2.Text
    wsLog.Range("J3").Value = Me.TextBox3.Text
    wsLog.Range("J4").Value = Me.TextBox4.Text
    
    If wsLog.Range("J3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "no Quantity has been entered"
        Exit Sub '?????
    End If
    
    found = wsLog.Range("Z4").Value 'what is this for?
    BHM = wsLog.Range("J1").Value
    DT = wsLog.Range("J2").Value
    
    r = 2 'start checking here...
    lr = wsInv.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row 'last value in col H
    
    Do While r <= lr
        If wsInv.Cells(r, "H").Value = DT Then
            iColRows = wsInv.Cells(r, "I").MergeArea.Rows.Count '?Col I is merged?
            'check each cell in (D to G) x (# of merged rows in Col I)
            For Each cel In wsInv.Cells(r, "D").Resize(iColRows, 4).Cells
                v = cel.Value
                If v = BHM Or v = "Misc." Then
                    With wsInv.Cells(r, "I")
                        .Value = .Value & wsLog.Range("J3").Value 'increment amount
                        found = "1"
                        Exit Do 'done searching...
                    End With
                End If
            Next cel
            r = r + (iColRows - 1) 'not matched, so skip to last "Extra" row before continuing the search
        End If
        r = r + 1 'increment search row
    Loop
    
    If found <> "1" Then MsgBox "no matching BHM for Detail #"

    wsLog.Range("J1:J4").ClearContents
End Sub

